# JSON writer doesn't include properties on classes derived from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have the following classes:

```
public class Goal : ObservableCollection<Activity>
{

  public string Name { get; set; }

  // constructors
  public Goal() { }
  public Goal(string name)
  {

    Name = name;

  }

}

public class Activity
{

  // properties
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Details { get; set; }
  public bool FilterMe { get; set; }

  // constructors
  public Activity() { }
  public Activity(string name)
  {

    Name = name;

  }

}
```

When I write this out as JSON, the Activity list with all public Activity properties is output correctly, but the Name property for the Goal is not included. What am I doing wrong?

```
// create a goal
Goal goal = new("Goal 1");
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
  Activity activity = new($"Activity {a + 1}");
  if (a % 2 == 0) { activity.FilterMe = true; }
  goal.Add(activity);
}

// write the output file
using FileStream fsWrite = File.Create("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Test.json");
JsonSerializer.Serialize<Goal>(new Utf8JsonWriter(fsWrite, new JsonWriterOptions() { Indented = true }), goal, new JsonSerializerOptions() { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull, IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true });
```

Here is sample output:

```
{
  "Goal": [
    {
      "Name": "Activity 1",
      "Details": "",
      "FilterMe": true
    },
    {
      "Name": "Activity 2",
      "Details": "",
      "FilterMe": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "Activity 3",
      "Details": "",
      "FilterMe": true
    },
    {
      "Name": "Activity 4",
      "Details": "",
      "FilterMe": false
    },
    {
      "Name": "Activity 5",
      "Details": "",
      "FilterMe": true
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the output above, the Name property for the Goal is missing. It's a public property, so I assumed that the Serializer would pick it up.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the code that can be compiled. I am not talking that the worst thing for a developer is to inherit list

Comment: It's a simple class and a simple call to the Serializer. The expectation is that the Serializer would output the public properties on the class, including Name, which is it not. If you need the Activity class, I can post it, but it's also very simple with three properties.

The inheritance of the ObservableCollection is necessary for the IsGouped function of CollectionView in .NET MAUI. I've been experimenting with it a bit. Hope that helps.

Comment: I need the code that created goal instance that you are trying to serialize

Comment: OK, added the Activity and goal creation code.

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) can output objects or arrays. It has no mechanism for outputting arrays-with-properties (and yes I realize that array elements are technically properties with numeric indexes, but shut up). How would it show that and not confuse parsers? `[ "Name":"Goal 1", { "Name": "Activity 1", "Details": "", "FilterMe": true }, ... ]`? That's illegal JavaScript syntax. There is no literal syntax for an array with properties.

Comment: As an example, in a browser console, enter the following: `var a = [{prop:"val"}]; a.propA = "valA"; JSON.stringify(a);` You'll get something like `[{"prop":"val"}]` with no mention of "propA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will never be working the way you want, and it is not a serializer problem, it is the way C# creates objects. Even if you try to create json the way you want manually using a text editor,  it will be an invalid json. You will not be able to use it. So the only thing I can recommed you , to change your class to this

```
public class Goal 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Activity> Goals {get; set;} = new();

  public string Name { get; set; }
   public void Add (Activity activity)
   {
    Goals.Add(activity);
   }

  // constructors
  public Goal() { }
  public Goal(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

and all your code will be working without any problem

PS.

I would be extremely interested to see a json you want after serialization, please fix json you posted  manually the way you want and show us.

Comment: Thanks, Serge. That's what I suspected. I just wanted to be sure I'm not crazy. There isn't a  lot of documentation on MAUI right now, so we have to depend on Xamarin documentation. The Xamarin CollectionView control has a grouping feature, which I would like to use, but it looks like it requires the inherited lists to work, vis a vis https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping. I hope to refactor a WPF application into MAUI, and it uses a different method to group things (CollectionView GroupDescriptions), which MAUI doesn't support. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome